# Reuse @model types in Amplify

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

there

Lets say I have a clean angular amplify project with one defined `@model` called `TodoItem`. Now I want to override the default create mutation with my custom created lambda (using `@function` directive). But I would like to reuse the default input `CreateTodoItemInput` that was generated for default. If i reference `CreateTodoItemInput` in `schema.graphql` i'm getting error during `amplify push` that there is no defined input with this name

Is there a way to reuse it or in such a case I need to create an identical duplicate input type?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using typescript, Amplify will generate a file that has types and enums matching your schema.

They stick it in the front-end: `src/API.ts`, but you can reference it in your backend.

Not sure if it's relevant (I stumble my way through the stupid build tools); but my Lambda's tsconfig.js looks like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../../../../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "es2020"
    ],
    "noEmit": true,
    "target": "es2020"
  },
  "include": [
    "./"
  ]
}
```

Inside my Lambda, I just grab a type when I need it:

```
import { OrderStatus, TriggerType } from 'API'
```

Comment: i want to reference it not just in backend but in backend schema that API is generated with in the first place...

Comment: Ah. I don't think you can do that. But the docs for @http seem to support what you're looking to do, so perhaps you can use that technique with `@function` as well. https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/custom-business-logic/#request-body